# Hello World not printing. Error

Tags: c

I am learning C.  I have been frustrated with this problem for at least 20 minutes now.  I can't seem to even get my hello world to print.  The problem does not even compile.

```
int main()
{
    printf("hello world");
    return 0;
{
```

What gives?

Comment: First of all, when posting a question about compilation errors, always include the complete and unedited error message log in the question. Secondly, even without seeing them I'm fairly certain that the error messages here would be clear enough that you could have found the problem by just reading them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h> // include this library header file to use printf()

int main()
{
    printf(“Hello world.\n”);
    return 0;
}                  // Replace “{“ with : “}”
                   // You were not closing the main body correctly.
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is opened needs to be closed:

```
    return 0;
} // change to closing bracket
```

Also, `#include <stdio.h>` in case you have not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the correct headers and that you request input after printing your message. If you do not print there is a chance you won't have enough time to see the message.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 

printf("hello world");
getchar(); //if you don't do this the hello world will be printed too fast for you to see
return 0;

}
```